# Позиционирование элемента html css

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка покупки стоял под картиной?[image: photosite]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
}
#block-body {
  width: 1035px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  height: auto;
}
header {
   width: 1035px; 
   height: 80px;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(122,122,122,0.5);
}
<!--#22B14C-->
#block-content {
  width: 1035px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.logo {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
}
.logo a {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: "Exo2-Bold", sans-serif;
  color:  #b2aeb2;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.use {
  color: white;
  
}
.web {
  color: #429595;
  background: white;
  padding: 2px; 
}
.logo p {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family:  "Exo2-Medium", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #22B14C;
}
.top-menu {
  width: 685px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
}
.top-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.top-menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 171px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family:  "ProximaNova",Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #121313;
  height: 55px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;

}
.top-menu ul li a:hover {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #22B14C;
}
.block-top-auth {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
  height: 80px;
}

.block-top-auth p {
  margin-top: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  
}
.block-top-auth a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #121313;
  font-family:  "Exo2-Medium", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.block-top-auth a:hover {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
  color: #124f2e;
}
nav ul ul .submenu-link{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display:inherit;
}

nav ul ul li .submenu-link{
  min-width:170px;
  float:none;
  display:list-item;
  position: relative;
}


/* Стили меню */ 
.submenu-link {
  display: block;
  width: 171px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "ProximaNova",Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #121313;
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}   

.submenu-link:hover {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #22B14C;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.submenu-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}

.submenu-content a{
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-family: "ProximaNova",Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128);
  border-bottom-width: thin;
}

a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}
.dropdown:hover .submenu-content {display: block;}
/*.dropdown:hover .submenu-link {background-color: #3e8e41;}*/

.fa {
font-family: "FontAwesome";
  color: inherit;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.image{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image img {
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: 10px;

}

.info h3 {
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.info-price {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.add-to-cart {
  border: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #8bc34a;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;

}

.price {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.product {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Шапка для сайта</title>
  <style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>

  <div id="block-body">

   <header>

   <!--// разметка для логотипа -->

     <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
      <!-- <span class="use">Вкус</span><span class="web">Няшка</span>-->
    </a>   
     <p>Онлайн магазин продуктов</p>    
     </div>  

     <!--// разметка для нашего меню -->

     <nav class="top-menu">
     <ul>
      <div class="dropdown">
       <button class="submenu-link">Каталог<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
          <div class="submenu-content">
            <a href="#">ОВОЩИ, ФРУКТЫ, ЯГОДЫ, ЗЕЛЕНЬ</a></li>
            <a href="#">fdddsf</a></li> 
            <a href="#">fdfddsd</a></li>
            <a href="#">fdfdd</a></li>
            <a href="#">fdfdsd</a></li>
          </div>
      </div>
       <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Обратная связь</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Корзина</a></li>
     </ul>  
     </nav> 

     <!--// блок с авторизацией -->

     <div class="block-top-auth">
     <p><a href="#">Вход</a></p>  
     <p><a href="#">Регистрация</a></p>  
     </div> 

   </header>

    <div id="block-content">
        <div class="container mt-5">
       <div class="row">
         
        <div class="col-md-">
          <div class="product">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" alt="">
          </div>

          <div class="info">
            <h3>Название ава</h3>
            <div class="info-price">
            <span class="price">256<small>₸</small></span>
            <button class="add-to-cart"><ion-icon name="cart-outline"></ion-icon></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>

       </div>
       </div> 
    </div>  
    
  </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym0iM.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym0iM.png)

Answer (score 0):

До блоку з класом product добавить `max-width -  я добавил 250px`

или опишите более детально как должно быть при 1 товаре а как при 2/4

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
    }
    #block-body {
      width: 1035px;
      margin: 5px auto;
      height: auto;
    }
    header {
       width: 1035px; 
       height: 80px;
       background-color: white;
       border-radius: 25px;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(122,122,122,0.5);
    }
    <!--#22B14C-->
    #block-content {
      width: 1035px;
      height: auto;
      min-height: 500px;
    }
    .logo {
      width: 200px;
      float: left;
      height: 80px;
    }
    .logo a {
      display: block;
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-family: "Exo2-Bold", sans-serif;
      color:  #b2aeb2;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .use {
      color: white;
      
    }
    .web {
      color: #429595;
      background: white;
      padding: 2px; 
    }
    .logo p {
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-top: 2px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      font-family:  "Exo2-Medium", sans-serif;
      font-size: 13px;
      color: #22B14C;
    }
    .top-menu {
      width: 685px;
      height: 80px;
      float: left;
    }
    .top-menu ul li {
      list-style: none;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .top-menu ul li a {
      display: block;
      width: 171px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family:  "ProximaNova",Arial,sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #121313;
      height: 55px;
      padding-top: 25px;
      cursor: pointer;

    }
    .top-menu ul li a:hover {
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
      color: white;
      border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
      background-color: #22B14C;
    }
    .block-top-auth {
      width: 100px;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 40px;
      height: 80px;
    }

    .block-top-auth p {
      margin-top: 12px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      
    }
    .block-top-auth a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #121313;
      font-family:  "Exo2-Medium", sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-decoration: underline;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .block-top-auth a:hover {
      transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
      -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
      -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
      color: #124f2e;
    }
    nav ul ul .submenu-link{
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
    }
    nav ul li:hover > ul {
      display:inherit;
    }

    nav ul ul li .submenu-link{
      min-width:170px;
      float:none;
      display:list-item;
      position: relative;
    }


    /* Стили меню */ 
    .submenu-link {
      display: block;
      width: 171px;
      background-color: #FFF;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: "ProximaNova",Arial,sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #121313;
      height: 80px;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 25px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: none;
    }   

    .submenu-link:hover {
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      color: white;
      border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
      background-color: #22B14C;
    }

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .submenu-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
      border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    }

    .submenu-content a{
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      font-family: "ProximaNova",Arial,sans-serif;
      font-size: 13px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128);
      border-bottom-width: thin;
    }

    a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}
    .dropdown:hover .submenu-content {display: block;}
    /*.dropdown:hover .submenu-link {background-color: #3e8e41;}*/

    .fa {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
      color: inherit;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .image{
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .image img {
      height: 300px;
      object-fit: cover;
      border-radius: 7px;
      margin-top: 10px;

    }

    .info h3 {
      font-size: 21px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .info-price {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .add-to-cart {
      border: none;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: #8bc34a;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 10px;

    }

    .price {
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    .product {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      max-width:250px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <title>Шапка для сайта</title>
      <style>
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>

      <div id="block-body">

       <header>

       <!--// разметка для логотипа -->

         <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
          <!-- <span class="use">Вкус</span><span class="web">Няшка</span>-->
        </a>   
         <p>Онлайн магазин продуктов</p>    
         </div>  

         <!--// разметка для нашего меню -->

         <nav class="top-menu">
         <ul>
          <div class="dropdown">
           <button class="submenu-link">Каталог<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
              <div class="submenu-content">
                <a href="#">ОВОЩИ, ФРУКТЫ, ЯГОДЫ, ЗЕЛЕНЬ</a></li>
                <a href="#">fdddsf</a></li> 
                <a href="#">fdfddsd</a></li>
                <a href="#">fdfdd</a></li>
                <a href="#">fdfdsd</a></li>
              </div>
          </div>
           <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Обратная связь</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Корзина</a></li>
         </ul>  
         </nav> 

         <!--// блок с авторизацией -->

         <div class="block-top-auth">
         <p><a href="#">Вход</a></p>  
         <p><a href="#">Регистрация</a></p>  
         </div> 

       </header>

        <div id="block-content">
            <div class="container mt-5">
           <div class="row">
             
            <div class="col-md-">
              <div class="product">
              <div class="image">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/No_image_available.svg/1024px-No_image_available.svg.png" alt="">
              </div>

              <div class="info">
                <h3>Название ава</h3>
                <div class="info-price">
                <span class="price">256<small>₸</small></span>
                <button class="add-to-cart"><ion-icon name="cart-outline"></ion-icon></button>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>

           </div>
           </div> 
        </div>  
        
      </div>   
    </body>
    </html>
```